# Converting WGS84 to UTM coordinates using R package gstat?

Tags: coordinate-system, r

I want to convert WGS84 to NZGD2000 using R package gstat but I cannot get the right result.

```
   # Define the coordinate systems

   wgs_co <- data.frame(lon=x, lat=y)

   coordinates(wgs_co) <- c("lon", "lat")

   proj4string(wgs_co) <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326") # WGS 84


   #convert coordinates

   UTM60H <- "+proj=utm +zone=60 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs"

   UTM60H <- paste(UTM60H, "+ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0")

   UTM60H <-  CRS(UTM60H)
```

it turns out

```
   [4003,] 352172.5 -4445766

   [4004,] 352174.1 -4445767 
    ... 
    ...

   [5000,] 352657.5 -4445754
```

The right coordinates should be around E 1,792,000, N 5,554,400 in NZGD2000.

Do you have any solution?

Comment: Your code does not convert the coordinates, you have to use `spTransform(wgs_co, CRS(UTM60H))`.

Comment: Also try `UTM60H <- CRS("+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=173 +k=0.9996 +x_0=1600000 +y_0=10000000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs")`

Comment: note this is *not* the gstat package doing this, the spatial data handling functions are from the sp and rgdal package which I guess gstat is loading when you load it.

Comment: @rcs Sorry I forgot to post this line. I have used `spTransform(wgs_co, CRS(UTM60H))` but it still doesn't give me the correct coordinates.

Comment: @Golden Jiang, I suppose gstat uses `spTransform` internally too. If the coordinates don't look correct to you, the destination coordinate system may be incorrect. try to use the epgs code instead of the projection string for UTM60H.

Comment: @dof1985 Thank you so much! Your code successfully converted! `UTM60H <- "+proj=utm +zone=60H +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs"
UTM60H <- CRS("+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=173 +k=0.9996 +x_0=1600000 +y_0=10000000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs")

d <- spTransform(wgs_co, UTM60H)
d`  Would you be able to give some explanations of this? I am still puzzled.  Great thanks!  @Spacedman @Farid Cher @rcs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsing [spatialreference.org](http://spatialreference.org/ref/?search=nzgd2000&srtext=Search) for nzdg2000 showed that there are many specifications that fit this coordinates system. Filtering for sort-of nationwide metric systems leaves us roughly with 4 projections:

- ESPG [2133](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/2133/) / [2134](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/2134/) /[2135](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/2135/): UTM 58S / 59S / 60S, respectively.
- ESPG [2193](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/2193/): New Zealand Transverse Mercator 2000

Judging by your expectation to an x coordinate that is far from the origin by more than 1 Million meters, I assumed that you needed NZTM2000. This coordinate system has the widest projection bounds (you can check the links to get projection's information), thus it is most likely to find coordinates that are most remote from the projection origin.

To conclude I think that [spatialreference.org](http://spatialreference.org/) is an invaluable resource when using projections, so whenever some problems occurs I check the database to see if any alternatives exist.